# Wait all subprocess to complete in python

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a method which executes a command using subprocess,
I want to call that method "n" no of times and wait for all "n" subprocess to complete 
for example:

```
import subprocess
class mysubprocess():
    def child_process(self,directory):
        self.process=subprocess.Popen('ls',cwd=directory)

    def execute(self):
        directory=['/home/suresh/Documents','/home/suresh/Downloads']
        for i in directory:
            print(i)
            self.child_process(directory)

        self.process.wait()

def main():
    myobject=mysubprocess()
    myobject.execute()

if __name__=='main':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store references to the `Popen` objects to call [`wait` methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait) of them later.
(The code in the question overwrites the `Popen` object with the last `Popen` object, and waits only the last sub-process.)

```
import subprocess


class mysubprocess():

    def execute(self, directory_list):
        procs = []
        for d in directory:
            print(d)
            procs.append(subprocess.Popen('ls', cwd=d))  # <---
        for proc in procs:
            proc.wait()


def main():
    myobject = mysubprocess()
    myobject.execute(['/home/suresh/Documents','/home/suresh/Downloads'])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

Other issues

- The code is passing the entire list (`directory`) instead of item.
- The last `if` statement should compare `__name__` with `'__main__'`.